# Google Cloud Run w/ Flask and Gunicorn: Nginx needed?

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn, google-cloud-run

I've followed the [Google Cloud Run Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy) which shows how to deploy a Flask app to Cloud Run, served with Gunicorn.

However, many places online (including [Gunicorn's own documentation](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html)) say that you should always put a proxy in front of Gunicorn, and specifically recommending Nginx.

Is nginx necessary when serving Flask apps from Cloud Run?

Or perhaps is it unnecessary (or less necessary) because Google Cloud Run already takes care of the proxying behavior you'd otherwise use nginx for?

(Note: The Flask app I'm running is just a REST API, so this particular service isn't serving any static files or anything like that.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Cloud Run, Google already implement a proxy front end (named GFE: Google Front End). One of the first assignment is to expose an HTTP**S** endpoint and do the proxy for reaching your Flask service exposed in HTTP. *I personally don't know if this front end is based on Nginx or not*

In any case, the Cloud Run python sample code is proposed with Gunicorn without other stuff by the Cloud Run team, I think you can bet on the quality of this example.

Comment: The GFE is definitely not Nginx. This link has information on the GFE: https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/security_whitepapers_march2018.pdf

Comment: Thanks John for the link !